# Error running gcloud auth This app is blocked

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to log into google cloud using this command in `powershell` to have permissions to my email.

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes https://mail.google.com/, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
```

In the browser I select my user and I get "This app is blocked".
[image]

I also tried to generate an application password, but when I enter my email and paste the generated password, it tells me that the password is invalid.

How can I remove this restriction? I am new to using google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can resolve this :
You need to:

- Create consent screen on your gcp project ( internal + just mandatory fields)
- Create credentials for Desktop
- Download oauth client
- gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=SOME_SCOPES --client-id-file=YOUR_CLIENT.json

Hope it helps